# SQL: Is it possible to return a table data type in a column of a select query?

Tags: sql, subquery

Can you return a table (or subquery) in a column?

This would be extremely useful especially when converting results to JSON.

For example:

```
select orderid, date, 
       (select itemdescription, price, quantity 
       from orderitems 
       where orderid = orders.orderid) as orderitems 
from orders
```

[image]

Comment: Various databases have various ways of doing it, but a simple approach would be to concatenate your 3 columns. Something like:
select orderid, date, (select CONCAT(itemdescription, "|", price, "|", quantity) from orderitems where orderid = orders.orderid) as orderitems from orders

Comment: Please indicate the database product. Do you mean SQL Server? Generally, relational databases only return results in a tabular format. You can certainly stuff a serialised version in JSON format in a column but I'm not sure how you would use it

Comment: That's not possible. No current DBMS allows you to select multiple columns in a scalar sub-select that is part of the `SELECT` list. Are you maybe looking for a join? Most DBMS have built-in functions to convert a result to JSON. Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: Your result set as presented is not in relational format.  Hence, it is not reasonable to assume that SQL can produce such a result.

Comment: I was hoping there was some standard that may work across all DBMSs or at least someway to do it in each of them but it looks unlikely. I'm surprised there isn't as this could be quite handy.  I ultimately need the result as JSON, so maybe Nick's "stuff a serialised version in JSON format in a column" might be the way to go. I will look into that.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing possible in SQL would be columns of type ROW MULTISET, which can be built/populated using (a.o.) COLLECT and FUSION operators.

This feature has been introduced in the SQL standard since probably 2003 (not sure of this), but it is extremely unlikely that any actual SQL product has ever bothered to implement this.  (Though I vaguely seem to remember I once said this before elsewhere and within the hour someone replied with an example of Oracle doing exactly such a query.)

My source for this is the free bookboon book "SQL : a comparative survey" by Hugh Darwen.  You might find this one particularly interesting if you come up with this sort of "advanced SQL" questions.